# How to determine current route and parameters in zf2

Tags: redirect, routes, zend-framework2

In a form I am developing, I want to abandon changes and redirect to the same route if a submit button named ‘reset’ is pressed.  The following code works for determining the current url and self-redirecting:

```
$hereandnow = $this->getRequest()->getRequestUri();
return $this->redirect()->toUrl($hereandnow);
```

I want to do the same using the route method:

```
return $this->redirect()->toRoute($current_route, $current_params);
     // OR
return $this->redirect()->toRoute($current_route_including_params);
```

However, this requires a determination of the current route and parameters.  How can I do that?

Comment: Why not use a `type="reset"` input button?

Comment: A `type="reset"` input button works, but I also needed a solution for a "save" button that does not close the form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer you question, current matched route name is available in MVC event, in controller:

```
$this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getMatchedRouteName();
```

matched route params:

```
$this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParams();
```

But, you can redirect to same URL (refresh page) in much simpler way:

```
return $this->redirect()->refresh();
```